# Audio visualizer for Tkinter program

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm5rh.png)Good morning.
I am creating an audio bar display, with distinct R and L tracks, displayed in a purely graphical way without a real input signal.
The program is there and the result too, but when the program is launched using '$ top' on the ubuntu terminal, it displays 'ibus-daemon' which fills my CPU to 100%.
You have to find a way to write the program so that not all of the CPU is used.

I tried to resolve the problem in this way:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-hahR1ldk1G31xZwf4cynyMQ4pIb3bV9/view?usp=sharing
The part of the code will print all the rectangles that will form the trend of the audio signal, but it will have to be graphically simulated in a random way, so I assume with some 'randInts'
I should minimize the creation of the rectangles. The goal is to create them once and print them "turn them on" only when the incoming signal (= randomNum) reaches a certain threshold

here is the picture of what the final program should look like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GU50SCvKzuxBC8KrUR6ISFiWV6DhyPM/view?usp=sharing

this is the part of code which overloads the CPU. I have to find a way to print the rectangles only once, and change its 'fill' property at each loop
here the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import randint
from tkinter.ttk import Label




altezza = 25
larghezza = 15
x1 = 20
y1 = 30
x2 = 0
y2 = 0
  
    if randomNum >=0:
        primoRett_1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_2.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_3.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_4.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_5.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_6.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_7.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_8.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
        primoRett_9.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green')
    
    
    
        secondoRett_1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_2.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_3.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_4.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_5.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect') 
        secondoRett_6.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_7.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_8.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_9.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')   
    

        if randomNum >=280:
            primoRett_10.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
            primoRett_11.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
            primoRett_12.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
            if randomNum > 300 & randomNum <= 370:
                primoRett_13.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
                primoRett_14.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
                primoRett_15.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
                primoRett_16.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
                primoRett_17.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
                if randomNum > 370 & randomNum <= 400:
                    primoRett_18.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')  
                    primoRett_19.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')
                    primoRett_20.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')
                  
    
    if randomNum2 >=280:
        secondoRett_10.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_11.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        secondoRett_12.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'green', tag='rect')
        if randomNum2 > 300 & randomNum2 <= 370:
            secondoRett_13.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
            secondoRett_14.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
            secondoRett_15.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
            secondoRett_16.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
            secondoRett_17.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'yellow', tag='rect')
            if randomNum2 > 370 & randomNum2 <= 400:
                secondoRett_18.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')
                secondoRett_19.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')
                secondoRett_20.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill= 'red', tag='rect')
    
   
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code should be edited in to be with the question.

Comment: Your code is too long. Please provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Also, avoid importing everything from a module and importing a module multiple times. You have imported ```tkinter``` 4 times and ```random``` 2 times.

Comment: _You have to find a way_... No, I don't, you need to provide your own efforts and ask a specific question, you had to find which part of code uses the most cpu, then ask about that specific part using a [mre]

Comment: Currently, your code is incomplete (there are over 40 undefined variables). Is there a reason you need so many in your example?

Comment: my variables are all declared, it just would have been so many more lines of code. I can attach them below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WfBAqsyttYaNfJQOi4nN5zg_nBI8epCO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.